# Can't access docker over the internet

Tags: nginx, ip, port, docker

I m going crazy trying to get a docker accessible over the internet.  I have created a geoserver container on Ubuntu 14.04 Server using:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:8080 -t eliotjordan/docker-geoserver
```

But when I try to connect to the server through a web browser the connection times out.  I know that the server is accessible through its domain name because I am running a web site on it, using nginx as the web server which I stopped to try this.

`docker ps` confirms that it is running:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
0e339661c232        eliotjordan/docker-geoserver:latest   "/bin/sh -c /opt/tom   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   sad_morse
```

And `netstat` shows that the port is open:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31023/postgres  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1047/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2882            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1339/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1067/redis-server 1
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      31023/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1047/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::2882                 :::*                    LISTEN      1339/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16267/docker-proxy
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60521           0.0.0.0:*                           1271/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1271/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*                           1091/snmpd      
udp6       0      0 :::35967                :::*                                1271/dhclient
```

I notice that it is only showing up as open on ipv6, so could that be the problem?  `ufw` is disabled and I can't think of what else to check.

I also tried proxying to it through nginx but had the same result.  For reference here is the configuration I used:

```
upstream geoserver_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:80;  # I also tried 0.0.0.0:80
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://geoserver_server;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my iptables configuration:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -nxvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 127 packets, 9452 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   84453  4816562 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 127 packets, 9452 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 99 packets, 7078 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 99 packets, 7078 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.32:8080
```

`Telnet` connects locally, but not from external.  Ditto `curl`.

Comment: Have you tried to access the container via IP? try "docker inspect <container name> | grep IP" and then try accessing your server via ip address.

Comment: @dcerecedo I can access the container locally, e.g. `links http://localhost` gets me a Tomcat welcome screen. I just can't access it from outside.  So using the internal IP address won't help.  Using the public IP is the same as using the domain name it maps to - the connection times out.

Comment: What do the nginx logs say? Do you have any iptables rules on your host? What happens when you `telnet host 80` from your machine?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel: I have no manually created iptables, and the docker rules appear to be ok.  I've updated my question with them. Telnet and curl work as expected from the host, but the connection times out from an external PC.

Comment: Do the nginx logs give you anything at all?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel No... they're empty. Which prompted me to investigate further and I found that some bright sysadmin on our network decided we didn't need port 80 open!  All working now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good stuff, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem that you see only ipv6, your server is listening to ipv4 request too. Could you run netstat and ifconfig in your container and post the results?

Answer (score -2):

As your netstat command shows, your docker is only listening on port 80 on the ipv6 address.

One quick workaround is to start your container specifying explicitly that you want to listen on the IPv4 addresses:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:80:8080 -t eliotjordan/docker-geoserver
```

Comment: It is listening on port 80 of the IPv4 address too, although you don't see a specific entry for IPv4.

Comment: how to you then explain the result of the `netstat` command the OP reports in the question? why for other ports both the ipv4 and ipv6 addresses are shown as listening? Also this behavior is described as a [docker bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2174)

Comment: I had the same output for one docker I run and it was listening on IPv4 too. I don't know exactly why this is the output; but I thought what you said when I saw that, until I found that it was wrong. Here you can see an example and another answer on the same topic, with a generic explanation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488299/dont-see-apache-running-in-netstat.

Comment: I just gave it a try on Ubuntu 14.04 and you are right, I reproduce the same `netstat` result and still can access the docker container on port 80 through the IPv4 address. What do you think I should do with my answer? delete it or keep it there since it could help others not to be fooled the same way I was?

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is to edit it so that you clearly explain which was our/your error, thus other people are not confused by this.